# How to Position Dropdown Menu

Tags: html, css

I have a menu with the tabs that for some reason don't want to nudge a bit closer to the left side of the menu. I tried removing all the other padding things and such, but it didn't affect that strange extra space between the edge of the menu and the tab text.

Also, I would like to make the dropdown to not have the padding around the ul li ul li tabs, only the parent tab itself. The image below shows the left being the current project https://codepen.io/gracethelittleartist/pen/EvMbNR?editors=1100) and the right shows what I would like to to look like.
[image]

```
ul{list-style:none;}
a{ text-decoration: none;color: black;}

.ul-li {position: relative;}

ul li {padding:10px;}

.ul-li > .ul-li-ul {max-height: 0;transform: scaleY(0);}

.ul-li > input[type="checkbox"] {
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.ul-li > input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .ul-li-ul {
  max-height: 9999px;
  display: block;
  -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
}


.ul-li {position: relative;}
.ul-li > .ul-li-ul {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  transition: transform 0s ease-out 0.6s,max-height 0.6s ease-out;
}

.ul-li > .ul-li-ul li a {
  display: block;
  background: #E3E3E3;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
.ul-li > .ul-li-ul li a:hover {background: #D1D1D1;}

.ul-li > input[type="checkbox"] {
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.ul-li > input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .ul-li-ul {
  max-height: 900px;
  display: block;
  transform: scaleY(1);
  animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: max-height 2s ease-in-out;
}
.ul-li > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + a[data-toggle="dropdown"]:before {
  transition: transform 0.6s;
}

nav ul li:not(.search):hover {background: white;}

@keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {transform: scaleY(0.5);}
  60% {transform: scaleY(0.25);}
  80% {transform: scaleY(0);}
  100% {transform: scaleY(0);}
}

    .wrap {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #E8E8E8;
  max-width: 330px;
  margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is this:

```
ul li {padding:10px;}
```

If you would specify this only for the parent, everything works fine.
Tipp: Use the inspection function of Google Chrome to (de)activate CSS styles.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was a much easier fix than I thought. Wow, it's been 2 years and I'm still a noob. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I have a problem. I did solve the first problem and second problem when having ul {...} instead of ul li {...} but now everything is squished and doesn't have padding and the only way I know how to make each individual tab have space around it is to add ul li {...} which brings the second problem (white between the dropdown as shown in the before of the image in my question). Here's the project (same link, https://codepen.io/gracethelittleartist/pen/EvMbNR?editors=1100). How do I change that and still have padding?

Comment: In your .ul-li-ul > li> a (very bottom) get rid of margins. Further, you can add here .ul-li > .ul-li-ul a 2px padding, so you get the small white rim as pointed out in your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, on the last of your css file

https://jsfiddle.net/Alan_van_Buuren/2d0Lnqvj/

```
.ul-li-ul > li> a{
  color:red;
  margin-left:-20px;
  margin-top:-20px;
 line-height: 20px;
 vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Hope helps you.

Comment: I'm sorry, the jsfiddle solution didn't really appear much different from my previous error, however the above answer from anki was successful. Please visit my updated codepen link (https://codepen.io/gracethelittleartist/pen/EvMbNR?editors=1100) to see for yourself what I was looking for. Thank you for your attempt, however, I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Oh... ok, i just move the items to left, so... this is a previus image https://ibb.co/cBWupF

Comment: I'm sorry I just realized you changed the dropdown excessive padding problem. Let me look into it for awhile. Thanks!

Comment: I see...it does serve as a good solution. Is there a way to stop it from happening altogether? Perhaps not. It's a good solution, thx.

Comment: @GraceSawyer i cant comment in the another ask, but... you need edit the code that i give you. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dzrxMo check the CSS in the botom

Comment: Yeah I got it. I did thanks. The only problem is that I can't add spacing between the parents tabs without messing up the dropdown (using padding or height).

Comment: Cool, you can, look this. .ul-li li:first-child  {
  padding-top:50px;
} is in the bottom css section https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dzrxMo